# How to group by arrays to a new array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have some arrays like these:

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4]
a2 = [6,7,8,9]
a3 = [2,4,6,8]
a4 = ['Mon','Tues']
```

I want to group them as

```
result = [
          [[1,6,2,'Mon'],[2,7,4,'Mon']],
          [[3,8,6,'Tues'],[4,9,8,'Tues']]
]
```

which means if I print the 0th row it will output:

```
[[1,6,2,'Mon'],[2,7,4,'Mon']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `a4` is of different length, but otherwise, `zip` is appropriate function:

```py
>>> a1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a2 = [6,7,8,9]
>>> a3 = [2,4,6,8]
>>> a4 = ['Mon','Tues']
>>> a4_long = [item for item in a4 for i in range(len(a1)//len(a4))]
>>>
>>> list(list(l) for l in zip(a1,a2,a3,a4_long))
[
  [1, 6, 2, 'Mon'],
  [2, 7, 4, 'Mon'],
  [3, 8, 6, 'Tues'],
  [4, 9, 8, 'Tues']
]
```

Comment: There are some differences. I expect the a4 should like this:[
          [[1,6,2,'Mon'],[2,7,4,'Mon']],
          [[3,8,6,'Tues'],[4,9,8,'Tues']]
] more specific,  [[1,6,2,'Mon'],[2,7,4,'Mon']], two 'Mon's in the same array

Comment: Sure, you need to convert tuple into list, if you need that

Comment: but  two 'Mon's in the different array?

Comment: oh, just noticed, let me think

Answer (score 2):

This the code for that:

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4]
a2 = [6,7,8,9]
a3 = [2,4,6,8]
a4 = ['Mon','Tues']
result=[[],[]]
[result[0].append([a1[i],a2[i],a3[i],a4[0]])if i< 2 else result[1].append([a1[i],a2[i],a3[i],a4[1]])for i in range(len(a1))]
print(result)
```

It outputs:

```
[[[1, 6, 2, 'Mon'], [2, 7, 4, 'Mon']], [[3, 8, 6, 'Tues'], [4, 9, 8, 'Tues']]]
```

Comment: the output is not what I expect... It should be like this:  [[1,6,2,'Mon'],[2,7,4,'Mon']]

Comment: I made it, Can you please check?

Comment: It's a bad practice and very anti-pythonic [to use list comprehensions for just side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects).